Sporadic 'goog is not defined' error when opening Google AppsScript dialogs
When opening a custom dialog in Google Sheets, using AppsScript, we sometimes get a blank modal and an error message saying 'goog is not defined'. This error is coming from one of the iframes on Google's domain, meaning it's outside of our control. That iframe is responsible for loading the third-party iframe where our code would live.
This error seems to be happening more often since Google's update to the AppsScript modals in the last couple of months.
Is there a way to work around this issue? Any suggestions on what can we do to prevent it?
See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/247184100/goog-is-not-defined?hl=en for another user experiencing the same issue.

I don't think there might be a workaround that still uses the Google Apps Script HTML Service because, as you mentioned, Google Apps Script users haven't access to the frames containing the Class HtmlOutput instance content.
If you haven't done so yet, search the Issue Tracker for issues about this problem and star it.
